# How to copy handlebars files to dist folder

Tags: node.js, typescript, handlebars.js, babeljs, npm-scripts

I'm using Typescript, which compiles from `src/` to `lib/` folder, and Babel, which compiles from `lib/` to `dist/`.

The issue I have is that I have `.handlebars` files within `src/email_templates/` that are not being copied over to `dist/` when I compile the app. Therefore when I run the app it fails with errors as `dist/email_templates/` does not exist.

I'm using `nodemailer-handlebars` package and have tried moving the `email_templates/` folder to the project root directory and setting `viewPath` to the folder, however this also fails as the app is located in `var/www/api.my-domain.com/`. It seems that the fact that I have periods in `api.my-domain.com` folder name causes viewPath to fail with error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
    at Object.resolve (path.js:1080:7)
    at ExpressHandlebars._resolveLayoutPath (/var/www/api.my-domain.com/node_modules/express-handlebars/lib/express-handlebars.js:342:17)
    at ExpressHandlebars.<anonymous> (/var/www/api.my-domain.com/node_modules/express-handlebars/lib/express-handlebars.js:223:35)
```

Here's my package.json script to build the app:

```
"build": "tsc && babel ./lib --out-dir ./dist ",
```

How can I change this so that it delete the current contents of `dist/email_templates` then copies the contents of `src/email_templates` to `dist/email_templates`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved using the cpx package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpx

```
npm install cpx --save-dev
```

Package.json:

```
- "build": "tsc && babel ./lib --out-dir ./dist",
+ "build": "tsc && babel ./lib --out-dir ./dist && cpx \"./src/email_templates/**/*\" ./dist/email_templates --clean",
```

```
npm run build
```

Answer (score 1):

> delete the current contents of dist/email_templates then copies the contents of src/email_templates to dist/email_templates

Two additional npm packages

- rmraf to delete old files in dist folder https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf
- mv to move new files to dist folder https://www.npmjs.com/package/mv

Comment: Thanks. I just found the cpx package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpx) which has a `--clean` flag that removes the need to also use rmraf. I don't believe `mv` works in the CLI (there's an open issue about it in their repo) but cpx works fine.